# Keras2.0 implement by theano backend

Tags: theano, keras-2

I am a new keras learner,i have some question, here is my code:

```
from keras.layers import Input

img = Input(batch_shape=(10, 3, 32, 32), name='input_img')
print(img.shape)
```

If I use tensorlow backend , it's print `(10, 3, 32, 32)`.
but if i use theano backend, it's print `Shape.0`.
Why?